# Dynamically add key value pair in jSON object using shell

Tags: json, shell, jq, keyvaluepair

I have a json object named `version6json` as follows

```
{
  "20007.098": {
    "os_version": "6.9",
    "kernel": "2.6.32-696",
    "sfdc-release": "2017.08"
  },
  "200907.09678”: {
    "os_version": "6.9",
    "kernel": "2.6.32-696",
    "sfdc-release": "201.7909"
  },
  "206727.1078”: {
    "os_version": "6.9",
    "kernel": "2.6.32-696.10.2.el6.x86_64",
    "sfdc-release": "20097.109”
  }
}
```

I want to add one more key value pair. The key is also a variable and the value too. bundle_release="2019.78" and value= {"release":"2018.1006","kernel":"2.6.32-754.3.5.el6.x86_64","os":"6.10","current":true}
 Now I want the bundle_release as key and value as its value, So the new entry would be "2018.1006": {"release":"2018.1006","kernel":"2.6.32-754.3.5.el6.x86_64","os":"6.10","current":true}

To achieve this, I am doing the folllowing

```
echo "$version6json" | jq --arg "$bundle_release" "$value" '. + {$bundle_release: "${value}"}'
```

Any help will be appriciated.

P.S- The question is edited as suggested by peak

Comment: What is in the `bundle_release` variable?

Comment: bundle_release="1034,567" I want to use this as key and a value against it. The value is {"release":"2018.1006","kernel":"2.6.32-754.3.5.el6.x86_64","os":"6.10","current":true}
This I am fetching from items array. Thats why "${items[$i-1]}" , it is the value.

Comment: Please fix the JSON. `”` should be replaced by `"`.  You can use jq to validate the JSON, e.g. jq empty <<< "$version6json"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, when specifying a key name using a variable in the way you are doing, the variable must be parenthesized, so you would have:

```
 {($bundle_release): ...}
```

Next, jq variables are not the same as shell variables and should be specified without quoting them, and without using bash-isms.

Third, when setting the value of the shell variable named `value`, you would have to quote the expression appropriately.

Fourth, to simplify things, use `--argjson` for `$value`.

Fifth, your sample JSON is not quite right.  Once it's fixed, the following will work in a bash or bash-like environment (assuming you're using a version of jq that supports `--argjson`):

```
bundle_release="1034,567"
value='{"release":"2018.1006","kernel":"2.6.32-754.3.5.el6.x86_64","os":"6.10","current":true}'

jq --arg b "$bundle_release" --argjson v "$value"  '
  . + {($b): $v}' <<< "$version6json"
```

Comment: I think I am not clear to u about my question. bundle_release is a variable having some value , I want to use this variable as a key and some other variable (say value) as value. The result you provided is not giving desired result. It is giving key and value same.

Comment: Your example only had one shell variable, so I used that. You could use —arg value "$value" for the other value, and then use $value for the value.

Comment: So if bundle_release="2098.09" is key and value={
    "os_version": "6.9",
    "kernel": "2.6.32-696.23.1.el6.x86_64",
    "sfdc-release": "2018.0505"
  }         then the command would be--> .     jq --arg bundle_release value '. + {($bundle_release): $value}' . I tried this but not working

Comment: The answer has been updated in accordance with the updated question.

Answer (score 1):

You're not giving the `--arg` option enough parameters: from the manual:

> `--arg name value`:
>
> > This option passes a value to the jq program as a predefined variable. If you run jq with `--arg foo bar`, then
> > `$foo`  is  available  in  the program and has the value `"bar"`. Note that value will be treated as a string, so
> > `--arg foo 123` will bind `$foo` to `"123"`.